# Problems using qxt in Windows

Tags: windows, qt, libqxt

I've been trying to get qxt working in Windows with MSVC 2010.

I have installed Qt 4.8.4 into "D:\Qt\4.8.4", and installed qxt into "D:\libqxt". I configured qxt as follows:

```
D:\libqxt>configure -prefix D:\libqxt -debug_and_release
```

And then compiled from the Qt command line:

```
D:\libqxt>nmake
```

No errors show up on configuration or compilation, but when I try to compile the examples, I get the following:

```
D:\libqxt\examples>qmake examples.pro

D:\libqxt\examples>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd displaysettings\ && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 1
0.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        d:\Qt\4.8.4\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile displaysettings.pro
        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -
f Makefile.Debug all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

compiling .\displaysettingsdialog.cpp .\main.cpp
displaysettingsdialog.cpp
D:\libqxt\include\QxtGui\QxtScreen(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include f
ile: 'qxtscreen.h': No such file or directory
main.cpp
D:\libqxt\include\QxtGui\QxtScreen(1) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include f
ile: 'qxtscreen.h': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'echo' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Examining the makefiles, I see that "D:\libqxt\include" is in the include path, but that isn't where "qxtscreen.h" is located--it's in the "D:\libqxt\src" tree. I could, of course, manually edit the makefiles to add this, but I feel like that shouldn't be required, and perhaps this indicates that I've missed a step. What have I done wrong?

Thanks for your help!